# Camera native application keeps opening itself

Tags: 8.0, lumia

On multiple occasions, the native camera applications opens itself. This can even happen when the phone is locked and posed an a table.
Is there a way to prevent this problem, or is this a harware one ?

Comment: Is the camera button loose, or does it launch on a hair-trigger? If so, it could be the button. Also what model phone do you have?

Comment: A lumia 520. I thought about the button, but it is stuck and doesn't launch camera when I push it.

Comment: If it is stuck, it could very easily be stuck in a position which is causing your issues. Also, you should be able to take the back cover off, which supports the button, and reposition it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes buttons can get jammed, if you get a crumb (or something else) stuck in there, which makes the phone think it's constantly being depressed.

For phones that have a removable cover (like the 520), removing the cover, and cleaning with a dry microfiber cloth may dislodge it.

For phones that do not have a removable cover, the best option would be to take it to an authorised repair centre, who *might* charge you an extortionate amount to do the same - if you're brave, and don't mind risking voiding any warranty, you might be able to dislodge anything fouling the button with a mini-vacuum, or air blower (similar to those used for cleaning DSLR sensors). If you do try this approach use the minimum amount of force required, to risk damaging the device - if you're unsure, take it to a servicing professional.

Answer (score -1):

You can try changing the side button.
I had similar issues, Nokia store replaced that faulty button